# How to get the birds daily observations data from different stations of any region

Tags: data-request, geospatial, time-series

I searched many websites and I cannot get the correct solution. If anyone have the answer, can share with me.

Comment: Welcome KarlMarx, but what is *birds daily observations data*? Do you mean which birds are seen where? But then: do you want dates, or times on the day? And what birds, what geographical region? In what format do you need the data? Minimum numbers? This question needs much more information. Please add more information your question according to [this guide](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Answer (score 1):

The Audubon Society has been doing its Christmas Bird Count for 119 years. You can get the data for each location between 1900 and 2017 here: http://netapp.audubon.org/CBCObservation/Historical/ResultsByCount.aspx

2018 data is here: http://netapp.audubon.org/CBCObservation/Historical/ResultsByCount.aspx